# What data structure discards the oldest item when a new one is added?

Tags: c++

I've been trying to remember this and it's driving me crazy.

Basically, it's like a small array, of let's say size five, and as you add items it starts to fill up. When it's full, and you add a new item, the oldest one (first added) is removed.

You can access the values by something like variable[0], variable[1] etc, where variable [0] is the oldest value, and variable 4 the newest.

Any ideas on what this is called? Is it a standard C++ type, or did I just see it somewhere as a custom class?

Comment: A _ring buffer_? There's no such thing built into the language, although I have seen several implementations.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Boost Circular Buffer

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/circular_buffer/doc/circular_buffer.html

From the Boost docs:

```
  // Create a circular buffer with a capacity for 3 integers.
  boost::circular_buffer<int> cb(3);

  // Insert some elements into the buffer.
  cb.push_back(1);
  cb.push_back(2);
  cb.push_back(3);

  int a = cb[0];  // a == 1
  int b = cb[1];  // b == 2
  int c = cb[2];  // c == 3

  // The buffer is full now, pushing subsequent
  // elements will overwrite the front-most elements.

  cb.push_back(4);  // Overwrite 1 with 4.
  cb.push_back(5);  // Overwrite 2 with 5.

  // The buffer now contains 3, 4 and 5.

  a = cb[0];  // a == 3
  b = cb[1];  // b == 4
  c = cb[2];  // c == 5
```

Comment: Would you rather re-write it from scratch than re-use it?

Comment: @Mark: No, but answers with boost get higher upvotes simply because you mention it.

Comment: I agree that mentioning Boost is not by itself sufficient reason for voting an answer up, as Dario's comment suggests. But you still voted this up, didn't you, @0A0D? It tells the common name of the requested data structure, and it refers to an existing, high-quality implementation of that data structure. The only way it could be better is if it addressed the part of the question suggesting that standard C++ includes such a type.

Comment: @Rob: The OP simply asked what the name of the data structure was called, not that how you implement it in boost. But shadamn, look at those upvtotes. I guarantee if boost wasn't mentioned the upvotes would be less.

Comment: @0A0D: Or perhaps these upvotes are there because using `boost::circular_buffer` is the right thing to do ? You should actually care less about upvotes and more about your answers. This one gives both the requested name (a "circular buffer") and an existing, well-written and ready-to-use implementation. That's why it got upvoted. People here are smart enough not to upvote an answer just because the 5 letters "boost" are part of it.

Comment: @ereOn: We will have to agree to disagree then. Seen it since day 1.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement this easily with a `queue`, although it doesn't have exactly the maximum-number-of-items behaviour you describe here.

Answer (score 0):

It's called a [FIFO buffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFO). Very common.

Comment: A normal FIFO is a queue while the OP's example is a special-case (ring buffer).

Comment: @Mark: "The first data to be added to the queue will be the first data to be removed, then processing proceeds sequentially in the same order." - That's what he is describing. A circular, ring buffer is a FIFO buffer.